# How to Migrate Data from MongoDB-3.4 to MongoDB-4.0 directly?

Tags: mongodb

Currently we are using MongoDB-3.4 as a standalone service in our Application and planning to migrate to MongoDB-4.0.
As per our understanding direct upgrade from 3.4 to 4.0 is not supported (As per the mongoDB documentation).

Can we use below approach to avoid first upgrading to 3.6 and then to 4.0?

Take backup of the data from 3.4 database using mongodump and then restore to 4.0 database using mongorestore
We tested this sample data and observed it is restoring fine in 4.0, however we are not sure whether this option can be considered in production environment.

Thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have asked MongoDB themselves (thru Cloud Manager) what their strategy is. Will get back when I get answer.